# How to clear a specific / particular error from browser console using code?

Tags: javascript, browser, error-handling, console, console.log

**I want to clear one specific error that prints in browser console.** I don't want to use try catch or any other thing and not display it.

I want it to be displayed and than clear it. Something like clearing the last error or previous error from console is fine as well

Comment: By `clear`, do you mean you don't want some error to show in console?

Comment: Console has number of errors but I want to delete one particular error. console.clear() deletes the whole console but I don't want that. Hiding error might not work for me. But let me know if you know anything related I will give it a try.

Comment: @MartinZhai Clearing last error from console should work as well.

Comment: `console` doesn't have such method. Still don't understand why you want to do it.